# How come you can cast a pointer to an integer, but not a double? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I'm doing a random exercise where, given an integer array and double array, you are supposed to calculate the size of an integer and a double.

For the integer size, I simply use two pointers to point to two adjacent arrays, then I find their difference. Because pointer arithmetic calculates this as a difference of 1, I casted the pointers as integers because I assumed the pointers would explicitly refer to 4 bytes of memory, and I got the right result (4).

Now, I try the same exact thing for doubles, but I get this error: `pointer value used where a floating point value was expected`

A possible guess is that doubles are 8 bytes, whereas pointers are 4 bytes.  But I' not sure if that actually matters.

Any insights?

my exact line:

```
int doubSize = (double)doubPtr2 - (double)doubPtr1;
//where doubtPtr1 and doubPtr2 poiny to two adjacent indexes of double array
```

Comment: This problem does not require any such cast, nor does it even require different code for an array of any type.

Comment: Are you not allowed to use ``sizeof``? Also code samples would be quite useful.

Comment: @aruisdante sizeof is not allowed.

Comment: The given function is simply a double array of size 10, and two double pointers, so I would like to utilize all three of those.  Casting was the only solution I could think of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard allows casting pointers to integer types, though unless the type is big enough, casting back won't recover the original pointer. Still, the actual mapping is implementation-defined though there is a suggestion it should mimic the underlying memory architecture, which sharply limits the utility of doing so. No such licence is given for floating-point types.
Take a look at `intptr_t` for a guaranteed-big-enough type.

Anyway, the better (and correct) way is getting those pointers to adjacent array elements, casting them to `char*` (`char` is guaranteed to be one byte big, a byte is not guaranteed to be an octet), and than subtracting them. (Result type should be `size_t` as for the operator)

That presupposes that for your exercise, `sizeof` was arbitrarily banned, which would otherwise be the solution of choice here.

Comment: @Dedupilcator May I ask the reasoning behind casting to char*?

Comment: @SpagGuy, it is because a char is one byte long. The pointer arithmetic on it will give actual bytes. If you cast it to something like an int, for example, your result would be in sizeof(int).

Comment: @TRKemp  Hm ok, I'm extremely new to C and would love to make sense of this.  I'm actually confused with the whole casting thing and feel like my integer solution was lucky (the exercise mentioned casting, so I thought it had to do with the solution).
An array of integers takes up 4 bytes per index of the array.
Any pointer contains 4 bytes of data pointing to an address.
Let's say you point an int pointer to the first index of an integer array.  It then refers to the 4 bytes of memory of that integer.

Comment: You point a char pointer to the second index of that integer array.
Because a char pointer normally points to 1 byte, what part of the array's memory does the char pointer actually point to, now?  The 5th byte?  Or another 4 bytes (5th-8th bytes)?

Comment: If you do this, "`char* b=&i[1]`", where `i` is an `int` array, `b` will point to the second element of the `i` array, which is the fifth byte of the array. This assumes that an `int` is four bytes long. When I find a concept like this confusing, I often write a little program and play with it in the debugger.

Comment: @TRKemp Added the additional background and some more. Something came up and I could not answer earlier.

Comment: Much thanks to both of you!

I'm going over some notes and this does seem to make sense now.  Since a char* will only point to 1 byte, it will capture the first byte of an element.  That way the pointer arithmetic will reflect the actual byte-distance between each element.

Answer (score 0):

Casting double pointer to a double isn't doing what you think it's doing, or at least I don't think it is... see for example:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
  double *a;
  double *b;
  double dummy[3];
  a = &dummy[0];
  b = &dummy[1];

  int *ai;
  int *bi;
  int dummyi[3];
  ai = &dummyi[0];
  bi = &dummyi[1];
  char *ac;
  char *bc;
  ac = (char *)a;
  bc = (char *)b;
  printf("Check for double: %d vs %d\n",sizeof(double),bc-ac);
  ac = (char *)ai;
  bc = (char *)bi;
  printf("Check for int: %d vs %d\n",sizeof(int),bc-ac);


}
```

(Print outs:

```
Check for double: 8 vs 8
Check for int: 4 vs 4
```

)

Comment: I'm not sure how that addresses the casting of a double pointer to a double.  However, I'm also confused as to why the (char *) cast works (because it appears to be working in this code)?

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking it.  A pointer is an address, which is just a number.  When you have an array of whatever type, each one is at the next available address.  So, to find out the size of the type, you just need the addresses of adjacent entries in the array.

```
double tmp[2];
int size = (char *)(&(tmp[1])) - (char *)(&(tmp[0]));
```

The addresses have to be cast to `char *` in order to get the address of the first byte of the data type by treating the address space as storing bytes rather than whatever the data type is.